# Could have - Would have been able - Could have been able

Tags: modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

Is there any difference between:

*I **could have done** it*

*I **would have been able** to do it*

*I **could have been able** to do it*

I think the third one is excessive because it has two the same elements of possibility while the two first ones seem to be equal

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I have quoted definitions of **could** from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/could).

> I could have done it
>   I would have been able to do it

The first two sentences have roughly the same meaning. In the first sentence, **could** has the meaning "used to talk about what someone or something **was able** or allowed to do". I am stating that, at the time, I had the ability to do it, but did not. The context would indicate whether this was because I decided not to, or because I was not given the opportunity or permitted to do so.

The first sentence might have a slight suggestion that I decided not to, and second sentence that I was not given the opportunity or permitted.

> I could have been able to do it

This adds an extra degree of uncertainty: here, **could** is this meaning: "used to express possibility, especially slight or uncertain possibility". It suggests that I am uncertain that I would have had the ability to do it, had the opportunity arisen.